# Can anyone out there offer any assistance on the translation and meaning of these two seals? (Characters identified: 國湧 化吉)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

**These two seals are located on a very large painting of flowers and fruit. So far I've only been able to translate the title which was done in cursive script. Is anyone familiar with these two unusual seals?[image]**

Comment: @dROOOze , isn’t it read as “化吉”, the second seal?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 Maybe - I can't interpret what they mean! I'll change it if you can explain it :)

Answer (score 3):

the top seal is “國湧”; the bottom seal is “化吉”, the art name (號), plus a graphic of “mickey” ¹ at the leftmost

a google search would reveal:

the above mentioned seals might belong to an artist “鄭國湧”, with an art name “化吉”; whom was born in 1960, in which, the chinese zodiac is mouse.

[鄭國湧簡歷](https://3g.163.com/dy/article/GQ7BVFGL0552F3MN.html)

¹ “mickey” 者・mouse 也・it’s head is at the top, looking at the right :)

“化吉”, might derived from “逢凶化吉”. that, for calligraphy or paintings, a “mickey” is ferocious (it might eat, then destroy the valuable artefacts).

so, a seal with “化吉” and a graphic of “mickey” is, . . . kind of a well-wishes

have fun :)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to go with the first answer thank you very much greatly appreciated